# How to fix 'Missing an assemble reference error' in Unity3D

Tags: .net, unity-game-engine, mono

I have scripts that uses Serialized field that I can change it via GUI of unity3D but I cannot see any options from Unity3D screen. This is my Unity3D screen:

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbWd0.jpg)

And this is my player settings:

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Kq5G.jpg)

Comment: Unable to view screenshots but are the fields public?

Comment: @kgrwhite yes, they're public, I also updated the links.

Comment: Are scripts inherit from MonoBehaviour?

Comment: @vmchar yes, they're.

Comment: Your scripts don't compile. Why they don't compile, we cannot say without seeing the scripts and error messages. Considering the title of your question, I'd assume that you are missing an include.

Comment: @Piflik actually, this code is working in another pc perfectly with the same version of Unity3D.

Comment: In that case, my second guess would be that the machine it doesn't work on misses some dll that your code references. But again, without seing your code and the error messages, all anyone here can do is guess.

Comment: @Piflik, thanks for all of your help, I deleted and re installed unity. It worked like a charm.